# If P(i) is true for all integers i with 2≤i≤k as inductive hypothesis, then why also p(t) is true by the inductive hypothesis?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

> "Let P(n) be the property
>
> n is divisible by a prime number. 
>    We prove that P(n) is true for all integers n with n> 1.
>   Basis step. If n=2, then P(n) is true because 2 is a prime and every number divides itself.
>
> **Inductive step. Let k be some integer with k≥2 and assume,   as induction hypothesis, that P(i) is true for all integers i with $2\le i\le k$**.
>
> We have to show that P(k+1) is true, i.e., that k+1 is divisible by a prime.
>
> We distinguish two cases.
>
> Case (i). If k+1 is a prime, it is divisible by a prime (namely by itself).
>
> Case (ii). If k+1 is not a prime, then it is a product **k+1 = s$\cdot$ t**  of  two integers s and t, such that  1 < s < k+1 and 1 < t < k+1.
>
> **By the induction hypothesis, t is divisible by a prime.**"

http://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~skiena/113/lectures/lecture20/lecture20.html

"P(i) is true for all integers i with 2≤i≤k." That is, p(i) is divisible by a prime number from 2 through k as explained in the given text.

But why in the "k+1 = s ㆍ t", t is divisible by a prime? I don't see in the **induction hypothesis** in the third paragraph that defines 2≤t≤k. If it's left out in the context, can you show the inductive hypothesis that makes p(t) true in "k+1 = s ㆍ t"?

Comment: The proper divisors of $n$ are strictly less than $n$.  If $s$ is a proper divisor then $s>1$ so $t=\frac {k+1}{s}<k+1$.  Since $s<k+1$ we also get $t>1$, hence the inductive hypothesis applies to $t$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because $2\le s,t\le k$ by definition of a non-trivial factorisation of $k+1$.

Comment: Oh, Since s, t ∈ Z,  

"1 < s < k+1 and 1 < t < k+1." 
⇔2≤s≤k and 2≤t≤k 

Then from "induction hypothesis, that P(i) is true for all integers i with 2≤i≤k", we can apply P(s), P(t) are true. Now I understand the proof completely.